# Angular starts listening on AppData/Local/Programs/Git

Tags: angular, git

After my active directory password changed, I tried updating my Git password. Now when I run ng serve on any scripts, I receive this message:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost: 4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/AppData/Local/Programs/Git **
```

Any help would be appreciated. I ran the following commands prior to this problem:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
git config --global --unset user.password
```

How do I revert back so that Angular builds properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to delete the repo and clone it again.

It seemed the git commands affected the local git repo.